# Access array with Node.js and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to access to an array over Mongoose and filter over array length like that:

**MongoDB**

```
{"likelist" : [ "5778173453f8f28a119d6eaa", "5778173453f8f28a119d6eab" ], "unlikelist" : [ "57781e7978ac42eb027d3728" ] }
```

**Node.js**

```
var likelistSum = req.body[0]['likelist'].length;

Data.find({$and:[query,{"likelistSum":{$gt:0}}]}).limit(req.body.limit).lean().exec(function (err,data) {
    console.log(data)

});
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are you sending to the server exactly ?

Comment: You cannot use likelistSum in query as property of document

Answer (score 0):

Try
req.body[0].likelist.length;

Maybe you need to parse the result to json, then:
JSON.parse(req.body[0]).likelist.length

Comment: I am getting: "Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0" with JSON.parse() and without JSON.parse(): ""Cannot read property 'likelist' of undefined"

Comment: I think your req.body is undefined. Did you try to print it out?